# Why Arrays.Stream () does not modify int[] inside of a method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, pass-by-value

Am trying to process some bit-wise operations on int[] of numbers. For each operation I create a separate static method directly inside of Main class and pass the numbers array as well the bit position that I want to modify. It's really nothing interesting.

My question is probably very stupid but since Java is ALWAYS Passing By Value why my methods is not changing my source when I use Arrays.stream(numbers[])... but only when I use for-loop.

In both cases I am passing the reference to the array why it is not working , please help this makes me crazy :(

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    int [] numbers = new int[n];
    for (int i =0; i < n; i++) {
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    }

    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (!"party over".equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
        String operation = line.split("\\s+")[0];
        int position = Integer.parseInt(line.split("\\s+")[1]);
        switch (operation) {
            case  "-1":
                flipTheBitAtPosition (numbers, position);
                break;
            case "0" :
                turnBitAtPositionToZero (numbers, position);
                break;
            case "1":
                turnBitAtPositionToOne(numbers, position);
                break;
        }


        line = reader.readLine();
    }

    Arrays.stream(numbers).forEach(x-> System.out.println(x));
}

private static void turnBitAtPositionToOne(int[] numbers, int position) {
    int mask = 1 <<position;
   //this does not modifty the numbers array
    Arrays.stream(numbers).map(x-> x|mask);

    //this does modify the numbers array Why ?!
    for (int i =0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] |= mask;
    }

}

private static void turnBitAtPositionToZero(int[] numbers, int position) {
    int mask =  ~(1 <<position);
    //this does not modifty the numbers array
    Arrays.stream(numbers).map(x->x & mask);
}

private static void flipTheBitAtPosition(int[] numbers, int position) {
    int mask = 1 <<position;
    //this does not modifty the numbers array
   Arrays.stream(numbers).map(x->x ^ mask);

}
```

}

Comment: Why do you think it should? What gave you that impression that `Arrays.stream` does anything to the input array?

Comment: You should make a smaller example, with less logic in it, to test stuff and to ask questions here. Make an example with one method and without so much branching.

Comment: Also, look up intermediate and terminal operations.

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.stream(numbers).map(x-> x +2);
```

This code creates a stream of integers then maps it into a modified stream of integers. At no point does it assign values to an array, nor does it return an array via terminal operation. This may be considered a work-in-progress stream, since you have not invoked any terminal operation, such as toArray or forEach.

So, using a Stream, you basically have two options. Either:

1. return a new array and then assign it to (or copy it into) the original variable.
2. or use forEach to assign each index... this is like a Stream version of a for loop.

If you go with option #1 then you will use `toArray(int[]::new)`, or similar.

If you go with option #2 then I would recommend starting with `IntStream.range(numbers.length)` since this will make it easy to assign at the given indexes.

Answer (score 0):

"map()" is not supposed to change the original stream (which is immutable anyway AFAIK). It just returns a new stream (don't worry about the underlying storage efficiency, because it's just a stream, but still). If you want to, you can just catch the new result into a new variable. But in your case, the 'for' loop seems good enough.